# Grouping data values in array elements

Tags: php, arrays

I have a form which contains form fields like this:

```
<form action="versions000003.php" method="post">
    <input type='hidden' name='method' value='recalculate' />
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td><input type='checkbox' id='thread_1|1' name='add[]' value='1|1' /></td>
        <!-- ... increment to 43 -->
        <td><input type='checkbox' id='thread_1|43' name='add[]' value='1|43' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td><input type='checkbox' id='thread_2|1' name='add[]' value='2|1' /></td>
        <!-- ... increment to 43 -->
        <td><input type='checkbox' id='thread_2|43' name='add[]' value='2|43' /></td>
        </tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td><input type='checkbox' id='thread_3|1' name='add[]' value='3|1' /></td>
        <!-- ... increment to 43 -->
        <td><input type='checkbox' id='thread_3|43' name='add[]' value='3|43' /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button type='submit' class='btn btn-danger'>Go</button>
</form>
```

Once the form is submitted, I do this:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    $mode = $_POST['method'];

    if ($mode = "ReCalculate") {

        if (is_array($_POST['add'])) {

            print_r($_POST['add']);

            foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
             print_r($value);

        }

    }

}
```

The resulting array, depending on what is selected, might look like this, for example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1|1
    [1] => 1|2
    [2] => 1|3
    [3] => 1|4
    [4] => 1|5
    [5] => 1|6
    [6] => 1|32
    [7] => 1|35
    [8] => 2|1
    [9] => 2|5
    [10] => 3|1
    [11] => 3|8
    [12] => 3|11
    [13] => 3|13
    [14] => 3|35
)
```

I'd like to work out how to change the form handling logic, ending up with 3 elements in the array in this example. I'd like to group the values after the pipes, by the value before the pipe - so ending up with:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1|1,2,3,4,5,6,32,35
    [1] => 2|1,5
    [2] => 3|1,8,11,13,25
)
```

Is that possible - if so, I'd appreciate any advice on how I can achieve that result please. Thanks

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to give already different names in html:  `name='add1[]'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through your `$_POST` and [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) using the `|` delimiter

```
$array = array('1|1','1|2','2|1','2|5','3|1','3|8');
//simplified version of your array

$new_array = array();
//define a new array  that will be built in the loop below in your desired format

foreach($array as $item){ //loop through original array

    $parsed_item = explode('|',$item); 
   //explode each item to split elements using the | as delimiter

    if(isset($new_array[$parsed_item[0]])){
         //if $new_array with the current key already exists add new value to existing array (concatenate with a comma to existing value)
        $new_array[$parsed_item[0]] = $new_array[$parsed_item[0]].','.$parsed_item[1];

    }else{ 
        //else create new value on array
        $new_array[$parsed_item[0]] = $parsed_item[0].'|'.$parsed_item[1];
    }
}
```